# How can I compute the totals in the footer of a dynamically created gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my code I create some gridviews dynamically. For each of these gridviews I want to show a footerrow with the totals from each column. How can I do this?

This is my code to create the gridviews:

```
            gv_arr(chart_count) = New GridView
            gv_arr(chart_count).ID = "gv" & chart_count.ToString
            gv_arr(chart_count).DataSource = dt
            If statistieksoort = LnxEnum.EBIChartType.DataGridView Then 'DataGridView
                gv_arr(chart_count).Visible = True

                'Footer voor de totalen tonen indien nodig
                gv_arr(chart_count).ShowFooter = True                    
            Else
                gv_arr(chart_count).Visible = objBichart.ShowGridView
            End If
            gv_arr(chart_count).DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to total the columns you want to total in the rowDataBound event for each data row and then insert the totals in the footer row in the same event.

```
Protected Sub gridDetails_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Obout.Grid.GridRowEventArgs) Handles gridDetails.RowDataBound
            If e.Row.RowType = GridRowType.DataRow Then
                subTotal+= {column with subtotal value}
                taxTotal += {column with tax value}
                discountTotal += {column with discount value}
            ElseIf e.Row.RowType = GridRowType.ColumnFooter Then
                Dim totalText1 As String = String.Empty
                Dim totalText2 As String = String.Empty
                grandTotal = subTotal + taxTotal + discountTotal
                totalText1 = "Subtotal:<br />Tax:<br />Disc / Surc:<br />Total:"
                totalText2 = String.Format("{0}<br />{1}<br />{2}<br />{3}", subTotal.ToString("c"), taxTotal.ToString("c"), discountTotal.ToString("c"), grandTotal.ToString("c"))

                e.Row.Cells(5).Text = totalText1
                e.Row.Cells(6).Text = totalText2
            End If
        End Sub
```

I have found this works about 95% of the time. Some times if you are dealing with strange bindings, you may have to look into the databound event for totaling. The total variables are global scoped.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I still have a problem with this.

Because I have multiple gridviews how can I link a rowDataBound event to each of these gridviews?